# RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand is firing too much in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

I have a `CollectionView` in my .NET MAUI app that I use to pull a user's feed. I just implemented infinite scroll by adding `RemainingItemsThreshold` to the `CollectionView` but it seems to be firing more than I want it to -- see the code below.

I set the `RemainingItemsThreshold` value to `0` so that it wouldn't fire the command to get more items until there's nothing left for the user to see. It appears to fire as soon as I approach the final item. It then fires again while the last item is in view. If I move the last item up and down a bit, it fires again. How do I make sure the `Command` is fired only once and not repeatedly?

Is there a best practice to implementing infinite scroll with `CollectionView`'s in .NET MAUI?

Here's my XAML for the `CollectionView`:

```
<CollectionView
    x:Name="BizChannelFeed"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Feed}"
    RemainingItemsThreshold="0"
    RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding GetMoreFeedItemsCommand}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       ... // Left out for brevity
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

And here's the code in view model:

```
...
private int LastItemId { get; set; }

[RelayCommand]
async Task GetMoreFeedItems()
{
   await GetFeedAsync();
}

private async Task GetFeedAsync()
{
    var data = await _myApiService.GetFeed(LastItemId);

    if(data != null && data. Count > 0)
    {
       // Set last item Id
       LastItemId = data.Max(x => x.Id);
 
       // Process data
       ...
     }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just use a bool flag to only process one request at a time?

Comment: Sure, I could but is this something all developers resort to? I thought there might be a built-in way to handle the behavior to prevent repeated calls to the `Command`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this to handle this situation. I'm curious to know how others handle it.

In my case, using just the `IsBusy` `bool` value wasn't enough. I felt I was still making API calls way too frequently. So I added a new property to capture the last API call time stamp.

It looks like this:

```
...
private int LastItemId { get; set; }

private DateTime LastFeedUpdateTimeStamp { get; set; }

[RelayCommand]
async Task GetMoreFeedItems()
{
   if(IsBusy || LastFeedUpdateTimeStamp.AddSeconds(30) >= DateTime.UtcNow)
      return;

   IsBusy = true;

   await GetFeedAsync();

   IsBusy = false;
}

private async Task GetFeedAsync()
{
    var data = await _myApiService.GetFeed(LastItemId);
    
    // Set API call time stamp
    LastFeedUpdateTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;

    if(data != null && data. Count > 0)
    {
       // Set last item Id
       LastItemId = data.Max(x => x.Id);
 
       // Process data
       ...
     }
}
```